# Why can't I access a site I've just imported when central admin says I'm a site collection administrator?

Tags: migration, upgrade, site-collection

This is a slightly unusual situation.  I have a MOSS 2007 farm.  I do a database backup and restore to our dev farm and then do a database attach to our 2010 farm.

I'm secondary site collection secondary admin on all the site collections in the MOSS farm, and if I go to Central Admin on the 2010 farm, I'm still secondary site collection admin, according to CA.  However if I navigate to the site I get permission denied.  The fix is to go through central admin>Site Collection Adminsitrators and hit OK on each page, which seems a bit odd for me.

I've tried assigning myself site collection admin in powershell and, although I can change who's listed as the site collection admins, it has no effect until I go into Central Admin and hit OK.

Which is all a bit confusing, have I missed something?

Comment: After some reflection and exploration I've decided that it's best to go around this likley bug than though it.

What I did was go to the web application in Central Admin and edited the Uer Policy to add myself with full control over everything on the web application.

Comment: Is your new Web Application a claims based one?

Comment: Yes, but the web application isn't new.  It's just sitting there waiting for me to do a database attach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to migrate the users from classic to claims notation. Read the "Upgrade Notes" in Bill Baer's post: http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2010/04/14/claims-based-identity-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx